# include variable in JSON

Tags: node.js, json

I am experimenting with an API. Now I try to provide the field 'firstname' with a variable. But this does not work. If I type the text flat like the other fields, this works fine. However, I have no idea how to use variables in a JSON file. Is there anyone who can tell me this? Below you will find my code:

```
 let namePerson = req.query.name;

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = 'https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/3856575/fe126d58-b8ae-4bf3-a124-9dc1bcf8bca5'
      
      // Example request JSON:
      var data = {
        "submittedAt": new Date(),
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "email",
            "value": "test@abc.com"
          },
          {
            "name": "firstname",
            "value": namePerson,
          },
          {
            "name": "lastname",
            "value": "Doe"
          }
        ],
        "context": {
          "pageUri": "www.example.com/page",
          "pageName": "Example page"
        },
        "legalConsentOptions":{ // Include this object when GDPR options are enabled
          "consent":{
            "consentToProcess":true,
            "text":"I agree to allow Example Company to store and process my personal data.",
            "communications":[
              {
                "value":true,
                "subscriptionTypeId":999,
                "text":"I agree to receive marketing communications from Example Company."
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    
      var final_data = JSON.stringify(data)
```

So what's in my code is trying to read the url `/?name=test-user` and put it in the firstname field.

Comment: Are you sure that `req.query.name` has value?

Comment: haha okay i feel very stupid .. you are right the value is undifined.